# Is $(\mathbb R, \mathcal T )$ connected, compact, and/or Hausdorff, where $\mathcal T :=\{(−x,x)\mid x\in \Bbb R\}\cup\{\Bbb R\}$?

Tags: general-topology

> Consider the following collection of subsets of $\Bbb R$:
>   $$\mathcal T :=\{(−x,x)\mid x\in \Bbb R\}\cup\{\Bbb R\}.$$
>   Is $(\mathbb R, \mathcal T )$ connected, compact, and/or Hausdorff?

I found this problem in my textbook when trying to work through example problems and got stuck.  From the definition of connectedness and a some of the relevant examples I've seen, I believe that this space would be connected, but am not positive.  Any explanation or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you explain your thoughts in more detail, we will have a much better chance of being able to help you.

Comment: if the elements of the space are, w.r.t. the usual metric topology on $\mathbb{R}$, all the connected, symmetric subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, (including $\mathbb{R}$ itself and $\{0\}$), then what topology are you assuming on this space? do you think it is self-evident?

Comment: @DavidHolden, this is a topology over $\Bbb R$. You read it wrong.

Comment: thanks, yes! i got there in the end, with the help of the clarification by OP.

Comment: Note that this space is not even $T_0$, since $x$ and $-x$ are topologically indistinguishable for all positive $x$.  On the other hand, the subspace $[0,\infty)$ is $T_0$, but not $T_1$, since $\overline{\{x\}} = [x,\infty)$, so there are no closed points.  So I would say that this space is not Hausdorff for two reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Connectedness: Can you find $A,B$ disjoint open such that $\Bbb R=A\cup B$? They are intervals that contain $0$.

Compactness: $\Bbb R=\bigcup_{x\in \Bbb R}(-x,x)$. I don't think that you can get finite of them and make the reals. They are not bounded.

Hausdorff: Every open contains $0$. Can you find then disjoint opens?

Comment: @dfeuer, yes i know.that's why i deleted instantly. didn't notice it at first.Of course it is not Hausdorff.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $\mathbb{R}$ was disconnected. This means we can write $\mathbb{R} = U \cup V$ where $U,V$ are non-empty open subsets with $U\cap V = \emptyset$. You need to show this is an impossible decomposition for $\mathbb{R}$. Here is a hint, show that every non-empty open set $\mathcal{O}$ has the property that $0\in \mathcal{O}$.

Answer (score 0):

your edit has improved the clarity of the question. the topology of the symmetric sets means that the space cannot be Hausdorff, as, for example, $0$ is in every non-empty open set. it is connected for the reason already suggested - there are not enough open sets to disconnect it. as to compactness, the space as a whole is covered by all the open sets with the exception of $\{\mathbb{R}\}$ itself. you cannot extract a finite subcover from this.